# Excel Plugin - Reuse Azure AD Authentication Context Between Multiple Cube Connections

Tags: excel, vb.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-analysis-services

I have a VB.Net Excel plugin where I'm prompting users for Azure AD authentication:

```
Public Async Function ADLogin() As Task(Of AuthenticationResult)
    Dim accounts = Await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync()
    Dim firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault()
    'TODO: define scopes
    Dim scopes As IEnumerable(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult = Await AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
    If authResult Is Nothing Then
        ' A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
        ' This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
        authResult = Await AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes, firstAccount)
    End If
    Return authResult
End Function
```

I then use the resulting authentication token to do some external validation with a external API, the details of which are neither important or relevant.

This same "Azure Authentication Window" is displayed when I connect to a Azure Analysis Service cube. In fact, if I have multiple cubes on the same Azure Analysis Services service I will be prompted once for, once for each connection in the file.

Is there a way I can reuse the authentication session from my popup in my cubes(I'm attempting to validate the same user and Azure AD endpoint in both)?

My use case is that I typically have 10 or more cubes of varying types, all hosted on the same Azure Analysis Service instance and all being connected to in the same cube. It's quite annoying to have to re-verify my user account 10 times every time I open my excel file.